# how to recognize clicks of two different mouses?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mouse, mouseevent

I want to recognize clicks of two mice - is this possible? I have to do different actions depending on which button was pressed.

**UPDATE**: For example, two left buttons from two mice.

Comment: Different mouses or different mousebuttons?

Comment: For example, two left buttons from two different mouses

Comment: Possibly something of use here: http://superuser.com/questions/29432/using-two-mice-in-windows-7-dual-mouse-dual-cursor

Comment: (removed some off-topic comments)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to realize a kind of multitouch..

Take a look at [TUIO](http://www.tuio.org/), I've already work with it in the past, using two mouse!

Answer (score 0):

I know the raw windows API support this - I can't remember the exact library/API though. But it may need some P/Invoke. You could start by looking at the Touch SDK or [multitouchvista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/), which specifically has code for multiple mice. Alternatively, the [MultiPoint SDK](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/india/projects/edulab/multipoint.html)